# BottomAppBar with BottomNavigationDrawer connected to NavigationController

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

Hi I'm trying to use new arch components in my project. Short description what I want to achieve:

- When user is on `MainFragment` I want to display navigation icon (Hamburger) on BottomAppBar. User is able to click navigation icon and display `BottomNavigationDrawer`
- When user select some menu item, or click something on `MainFragment` he is moved to another fragment, let say `DebtDetailsFragment`. Then Hamburger should be replaced with 'Back arrow' by `NavigationController`

Below I pasted my `MainActivity` code. When I comment line with navigation controller, the Hamburger icon is visible and `BottomNavigationDrawer` is able to display.

But when I uncomment this line, the Hamburger disappear because `NavigationController` knows nothing about `NavigationView` used in `BottomNavigationDrawer`. I don't use `DrawerLayout`, so controller thinks Hamburger is not needed.

Method `setupWithNavController` can control Hamburger icon and back arrow, but I have to provide `DrawerLayout` as parameter which I don't use.

Documentation for this method:

> The Toolbar will also display the Up button when you are on a non-root destination and the drawer icon when on the root destination, automatically animating between them. This method will call [DrawerLayout.navigateUp] when the navigation icon is clicked.

So the question is, how to display Hamburger icon when `NavigationController` is connected with `BottomAppBar` but without `DrawerLayout`? I will handle hamburger click myself in `onOptionsItemSelected` method.

---

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelProvider: ViewModelProvider.Factory

    private val viewModel: MainActivityViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelProvider).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(bottomAppBar)
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.main_nav_host_fragment)
        //bottomAppBar.setupWithNavController(navController)
        
        onDestroyDisposables += viewModel.uiStateObservable
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(::render, Timber::e)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.bottomappbar_menu, menu)
        return true
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem?): Boolean {
        when (item?.itemId) {
            android.R.id.home -> {
                val bottomNavDrawerFragment = BottomNavigationDrawerFragment()
                bottomNavDrawerFragment.show(supportFragmentManager, bottomNavDrawerFragment.tag)
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return findNavController(R.id.main_nav_host_fragment).navigateUp()
    }
}
```

---

Without setted Navigation controller:

[image: Without setted Navigation controller]

BottomNavigationDrawer

[image: BottomNavigationDrawer]

With setted NavigationController - Hamburger invisible.

[image: With NavigationController]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `BottomAppBar` should never display an Up button as per the [anatomy of the BottomAppBar](https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-bottom.html#anatomy) - it should only ever display the drawer icon. As seen in the [behavior documentation](https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-bottom.html#behavior), the Up button should be displayed in a top `Toolbar`.

Therefore, you should never be calling `bottomAppBar.setupWithNavController(navController)`, but instead calling `setupWithNavController(navController)` using whatever top `Toolbar` you have.

To set up your `BottomAppBar`, you should instead set your own drawer icon and [handle clicks on the drawer icon](https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-app-bar/#handling-navigation-item-click) yourself.

The `DrawerArrowDrawable` class is available to give you a correct drawer icon:

```
val icon = DrawerArrowDrawable(bottomAppBar.context)
bottomAppBar.navigationIcon = icon
```

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the BottomAppBar with Jetpack navigation drawer component as following way in my app.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BottomAppBar bottomAppBar = findViewById(R.id.bottomAppBar);
        setSupportActionBar(bottomAppBar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, drawer)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:fabCradleVerticalOffset="16dp"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_baseline_menu_24"
        app:navigationContentDescription="@string/nav_header_desc"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar.Colored"/>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_send"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/bottomAppBar"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

The result will be like this

[image]